# Anonymous function in array

Tags: php, function

I have declared

```
$func = array(
    'a' => array(
        'b' => function() {
            echo "hello";
        }
    )
);
```

I try to call in this way but it doesn't work

```
$call = $func['a']['b'];
$call();
```

I get a error
**Fatal error: Function name must be a string**

How can I call the anonymous function? I'm using PHP 5.3.

**Update**
It works, I just used wrong keys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you did works. Try this:

```
<?php
$func = array(
    'a' => array(
        'b' => function() {
            echo "hello";
        }
    )
);
$call = $func['a']['b'];
$call();
```

See also [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Z8suVX).