# Convert Switch to Array

Tags: php, switch-statement

so I have a function that handles various other functions, and I use a `switch`statement to handle these functions with `cases` and `breaks`.

It all works fine. Would it be possible for me to change this into an `array` with `keys`?

Here's the code

```
switch ($intMultiFun) {
    case "a":
        handle a function
        break;
    case "b":
        handle a function
        break;
    case "c":
        handle a function
        break;
    case "d":
        handle a function
        break;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Anonymous function in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219382/anonymous-function-in-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$map = array(
 'a' => 'a_func_name',
 'b' => 'b_func_handler_name',
  ...
);

if (array_key_exists($intMultiFun, $map)) {
   call_user_func($map[$intMultiFun]); // optionally you can pass parameters too
}
```

Comment: `in_array` should be change to `array_key_exists` if you want to match the key (ie, a, b, etc).

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `in_array()`, it seems:

```
if(in_array($intMultiFun, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']))
{
   //handle a function
}
```

-short arrays syntax was introduced in PHP>=5.4, so in lower versions that will be

```
if(in_array($intMultiFun, array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')))
{
   //handle a function
}
```

*Edit*

If functions would be different, then you should hold them in array, like:

```
$rgFunctions = ['a'=>'funcA', 'b'=>'funcB', 'c'=>'funcC', 'd'=>'funcD'];
if(array_key_exists($intMultiFun, $rgFunctions) &&
   function_exists($rgFunctions[$intMultiFun]))
{
   $mResult = call_user_func($rgFunctions[$intMultiFun]);
}
```

Comment: I want a to handle a different functions and b to handle a different function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call different functions for every key:

```
$funcs = array(
    'a' => 'a_function', 
    'b' => 'b_function', 
    'c' => 'c_function', 
    'd' => 'd_function');

$funcs['a'](); // calls a_function
```

Comment: @pNure, how will you pass arguments?

Comment: `$funcs['a']('arg1', 'arg2', ...);`