# PHP, is it possible to use an anonymous function in array to get certain value?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$arr = array(
    'key1' => 1,
    'key2' => 'value2',
    'key3' => function() {
         if (someConditionSomewhere) {
             return 3;
         } else {
             return 'value3';
         }
    },
);
```

Let's look at example above. This is what I would love to get in PHP. Create an array, type determinant values there by myself and then for the dynamic value pass a function. I know you can pass anonymous function to arrays since 5.3. But I am not interested in the function alone but rather what it returns. So if I do this later: `$arr[key3]` I want to get either `3` or `'value3'` depending what is there. NOT the function itself.

Is it even possible in PHP?

Comment: not possible you have to call them manually in any lang

Comment: can you not write the function before and assign it to a variable then put it in an array ?

Comment: Of course I could. Question purely out of curiosity. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check if it's function and then use it

```
if(is_callable($arr["key3"]))
    $value = $arr["key3"](); //it's function lets add ()
else
    $value = $arr["key3"]; //it's not a function

echo $value;
```

or in shorter syntax `$value = is_callable($arr["key3"]) ? $arr["key3"]() : $arr["key3"];`

Answer (score 1):

not possible you have to call them manually in any lang.

```
$arr[key3] //will return the function reference. so, call that function to execute it.
```

//like this.

```
$arr[key3]();
```

**you can go through more at this** [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219382/anonymous-function-in-array)

Comment: I could swear you could do it in JS and JSON. But JSON is actually quite different thing.

Comment: no you can't you have to call them in javascript also

Answer (score 0):

can you not write the function before and assign it to a variable then put it in an array ?

```
function test() {
 if (someConditionSomewhere) {
   return 3;
 } else {
     return 'value3';
   }
}
$value = test();

$arr = array(
  'key1' => 1,
  'key2' => 'value2',
  'key3' => $value,
);
```